# How to determine when a item in a WebView is clicked?

Tags: android

Is there anyway to determine when a item inside of a WebView is clicked? 
Such as another link in a WebView.

I want to listen for these clicks and repsond to them. is there anyway to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call javascript onClick function and from there you can call java object which you passed using addJavaScriptInterface. 
This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) might help. Copied it from the link:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showAndroidToast(toast) {
    Android.showToast(toast);
 }
</script>
```

and Android is an object passed by writing following lines

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

Hope this help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the WebViews addJavascriptInterface(mHandler, "testhandler");

mHandler is a plain class that you can define to handle calls from the javascript. Check out [this](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/using-web-view-in-android-and-loading-data-over-network/#comment-9678) link for more info.