# Android webview image fullscreen on click

Tags: android, image, webview

I am working on a developing an Android application that displays news articles from a database through JSON. The article is in HTML format because the database is used for both web and the app. The code I have (below) works great. The format is the same on both web and phone when displayed in a webview, but I would like the images to be clickable, so they can can be loaded in a separate activity, and the user can zoom and such.

I guess I am just not using the proper wording when looking for an answer, because I cannot find anything that relates to this. I am assuming I would have to find the  tags on click and capture the url somehow, and then pass it to another activity. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this or not. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);
final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", product.getString(TAG_CONTENT), mimeType, encoding, "");
```

This code runs within a Async task that queries the database for info.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is HTML, you can use the `onclick` attribute of the `img` tag

```
<img src="myimage.png" onclick="javascript:window.location=this.src;" />
```

This will open the image up as the current window.

Or you can do something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947952/714151) and send the URL to another activity.